# Problem in Understanding the following steps in an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

While doing quartic integral,I was unable to understand the step that leads to the answer.

[image]

Can somebody illustrates me how do we got from first integral to the next one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just looking at the antideriavtive
$$I=\int\left(\frac{1-\cos (\theta )}{(1-a) \cos (\theta )+a+3}\right)^r\frac {d\theta}{1-\cos (\theta )}$$
making
$$\Phi=\frac{1-\cos (\theta )}{(1-a)\cos (\theta ))+3} \implies \theta=\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{(a+3) \Phi  -1}{(a-1) \Phi  -1}\right)$$ I let you the pleasure of calculating $d\theta$.

Replacing
$$I=\frac 1{2\sqrt 2}\int\frac{\Phi ^{r-\frac{3}{2}}}{ \sqrt{1-(a+1) \Phi}}\,d\Phi$$
Now $t=(a+1) \Phi$ to get
$$I=\frac {(a+1)^{\frac{1}{2}-r}  }{2\sqrt 2} \int \frac{t^{r-\frac{3}{2}}}{\sqrt{1-t}}\,dt$$